Middle path of buddha
Buddha used to teach always follow middle path. Don't you think life is not middle . For example he slept for only 2 hours and many others story which is extreme in some sense.

The term 'Middle-Path' is a specific term to refer to:

A Path avoiding sensual pleasures & self-torture (SN 56.11).

A Path avoiding the wrong views of self-eternalism & self-annihilationism (SN 12.15; SN 12.17).


It appears the Buddha actually generally slept for four hours per (the middle-watch of the) night plus, when he was older, would nap in the middle of the day during the hot season (MN 36).
For the Buddha, because he was highly developed in tranquillity meditation, he did not require much sleep. In other words, when the Buddha slept four hours per night, or even two hours per night, he was not engaged in self-torture.
Therefore, it is generally harmful for ordinary Buddhists to try to follow the sleep protocol of the Buddha. Its worse if a person is attempting to develop Buddhist meditation and they do not sleep enough  (because they will develop the hindrance of sloth & torpor). Sleep is only reduced after deep jhana meditation has been developed. In jhana meditation, the meditator can spend an entire night abiding in the radiating of bliss.

can i do meditation more than 1 hour continuously

The middle path (majjhimā paṭipadā) proclaimed by the Buddha is the Noble Eight Fold Path.

"And what is the middle way realized by the Tathagata that — producing vision, producing knowledge — leads to calm, to direct knowledge, to self-awakening, to Unbinding? Precisely this Noble Eightfold Path: right view, right resolve, right speech, right action, right livelihood, right effort, right mindfulness, right concentration. This is the middle way realized by the Tathagata that — producing vision, producing knowledge — leads to calm, to direct knowledge, to self-awakening, to Unbinding."

Noble Eight Fold Path is the path leading to the cessation of suffering - Nibbana.
See MN 117 to learn about the Noble Eight Fold Path.

I think one of the subtle misunderstandings of the middle path is that it is a standard prescription while forgetting that making progress is what is important. Progress here refers to the Dharma and the practice of the Noble Eightfold path. A good illustration of this is the often quoted sutta AN6:55 about Venerable Sona who received an advice from the Buddha to tune his efforts such that it is neither too slack nor too tight; just like a well-tuned musical instrument.

After some time Soṇa focused on energy and serenity, found a balance of the faculties, and learned the pattern of this situation. Then Soṇa, living alone, withdrawn, diligent, keen, and resolute, soon realized the supreme culmination of the spiritual path in this very life. He lived having achieved with his own insight the goal for which gentlemen rightly go forth from the lay life to homelessness.

Once the general direction (as prescribed by the Dharma) in practice has been clarified and understood, to progress further in the spiritual path would require a bit of experimentation and wiggling or customization to tailor the approach. If we view different individuals as different musical instruments then logic informs us that to tune every instrument as if they are all the same i.e. with the same amount of force regardless of the string thickness, length of string, material of the instrument and so on then the end result will be disastrous.
For example, there are people who work in office environment. They may make do with one or two meals a day and attempt to do intermediate fasting like monks do and still be very healthy. Then there are workers who engage in intensive physical labour and need to eat at least three meals a day just for their bodies to cope with the physical demands. A one-size-fit-all approach would not be pragmatic.
Thus, as we advance in the spiritual path, the middle path requires some customization according to one's own context e.g. personality and abilities. We should rely on progress in the practice as a barometer to judge if we had tuned our practice correctly to achieve the best result in accordance to our own circumstances.
Addendum

It is a known fact that the Buddha suffered from chronic back pain especially in his later life (MN53).

“Ānanda, speak to the Kapilavatthu Sakyans about the person who follows the practice for one in training. My back aches. I will rest it.”

It is also a known fact that people with chronic back problems suffered from sleep disturbances. I knew an ex-colleague who had a fall and suffered a slipped disc. One day, I asked why she looked so tired. She revealed that she was kept awake the whole night due to her back pain despite having pain-killers.
I, too, suffered a history of back problems and there are nights when I woke up due to back pain and had to sleep on another side. During the time of the Buddha, there were no supporting bed mattresses that keep the spine straight while sleeping. It could be possible that the Buddha was unable to sleep for more than a few hours due to back pain that gets worse the longer he sleep.
Therefore, it would not be wise to emulate the little sleep that the Buddha had especially if it hinders our practice. Again, the important point is progress in the spiritual practice and not following dogma blindly.

I will not explain the Middle Path which already has been explained very well by Dhamma Dhatu.
I will address another question.
You asked , Buddha slept only for 2 hours and according to you it is some kind of self-mortification, so it is not the middle path. Sleeping hours is a sanskhara. All sanskaras are impermanent. Meaning sleeping hours can change. It can become 1 hour or 2 hours or 6 hours or 12 hours. In fact there might be a case that there are no sleeping hours!! Your question indirectly asks why Buddha does that ? That is an invalid question. What is happening is that ignorance is manifesting. Ignorance is leading to sanskaras , sanskaras are leading to consciousness, consciousness is leading to six senses , six senses is leading to contact. Contact is leading to feelings. Feelings are leading towards cravings, cravings are leading towards clinging , clinging leads to becoming , becoming leads to rebirth , rebirth leads to ageing, and death and entire mass of suffering.
That is all there is happening.

There was a rogue athlete named Chongo, who wrote the first encyclopedic work on big-wall rock climbing, some 800 pages, based on his experience doing it in Yosemite for a number of years.
He is also the inventor of a training sport called "slack-lining" which is a form of tightrope walking on a loosened rope, just high enough of the ground that you can't fall too far. It is a literal example of finding "balance" - yes - in the middle.
The Middle Way Lord Buddha discovered does not become comfortable easily, but it's perfectly natural once you master it. To say it's not a struggle wouldn't be true, but struggle, like everything else, is conditional. It's not about asceticism, but it won't lead to hedonism, either. The development of character and ethics is essential with each step.
This is an analogy, but hopefully useful. I'll add references in the comments later. Time to sit.

I mean, he could, not sleep at all. But he did.
He completed all the Paramitha to sleep in the last life? He should not have slept at all(in my opinion), but he did.
All that Buddha did by spending a normal life walking, sleeping, eating, drinking, etc is to guide his followers.
Some try to meditate without any sleep. (extreme).
Some do only sleep.
Both are wrong. Everyone should get proper sleep. It's useful for a healthy life (body and mind).
